# linebreak after a certain number of columns

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I want to get columns written out in a single line after printing out a given number of columns in one line. The original files are in the form of

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
...
```

If I choose 3, the output should be the following:

```
A1 B1 C1
D1
E1
A2 B2 C2
D2
E2
A3 B3 C3
...
```

or if I choose 2:

```
A1 B1 
C1
D1
E1
A2 B2 
C2
D2
E2
A3 B3 
C3
...
```

I am thankful for any solution; awk, sed or bash are preferred. I am open to python...

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place for asking for people to write solutions.  If you show what you have tried, people would be very helpful in responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
$ cat file
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
```

```
$sed 's/ /\n/3g' file
A1 B1 C1
D1
E1
A2 B2 C2
D2
E2
A3 B3 C3
D3
E3
```

```
$ gsed 's/ /\n/2g' file
A1 B1
C1
D1
E1
A2 B2
C2
D2
E2
A3 B3
C3
D3
E3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v n=4 '{l=""; sep=""; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {l=l sep $i; sep=FS}; print l; for(i=n+1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' cols
A1 B1 C1 D1
E1
A2 B2 C2 D2
E2
A3 B3 C3 D3
E3
```

concat first n elements and print; then print the remaining one per line

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

**Input**

```
$ cat file
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
```

**when n=3**

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i>n)sub(/^/,"\n",$i)}1' n=3 file
A1 B1 C1 
D1 
E1
A2 B2 C2 
D2 
E2
A3 B3 C3 
D3 
E3
```

**When n=2**

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i>n)sub(/^/,"\n",$i)}1' n=2 file
A1 B1 
C1 
D1 
E1
A2 B2 
C2 
D2 
E2
A3 B3 
C3 
D3 
E3
```

**when n=4**

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i>n)sub(/^/,"\n",$i)}1' n=4 file
A1 B1 C1 D1 
E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 
E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 
E3
```